# How to filter for unique combination of columns from an R dataframe

Tags: r, filtering, unique

I am trying to filter out the duplicates of a subset of columns from a dataframe in R.

I am interested in filtering unique combinations of session, first, and last. The following is what my data looks like

```
                        session       first     last            city
1  9cf571c8faa67cad2aa9ff41f3a26e38     cat   biddix          fresno
2  e30f853d4e54604fd62858badb68113a   caleb     amos                
3  2ad41134cc285bcc06892fd68a471cd7  daniel  folkers                
4  2ad41134cc285bcc06892fd68a471cd7  daniel  folkers                
5  63a5e839510a647c1ff3b8aed684c2a5 charles   pierce           flint
6  691df47f2df12f14f000f9a17d1cc40e       j    franz prescott+valley
7  691df47f2df12f14f000f9a17d1cc40e       j    franz prescott+valley
8  b3a1476aa37ae4b799495256324a8d3d  carrie mascorro            brea
9  bd9f1404b313415e7e7b8769376d2705    fred  morales       las+vegas
10 b50a610292803dc302f24ae507ea853a  aurora      lee                
11 fb74940e6feb0dc61a1b4d09fcbbcb37  andrew    price       yorkville
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
unique(df[,c('session','first','last')])
```

where `df` is your data frame.

Comment: can you count them too?

Comment: @Climbs_lika_Spyder `nrow(unique(df[,c('session','first','last')]))`