# Calling recursive functions in R

Tags: r, recursion

Assuming I have a dataframe, df with this info

`group    wk  source  revenue
1   1   C   100
1   1   D   200
1   1   A   300
1   1   B   400
1   2   C   500
1   2   D   600`

I'm trying to programatically filter's down to rows of unique combinations of group, wk and source, and then perform some operations on them, before combining them back into another dataframe. I want to write a function that can scale to any number of segments (and not just the example scenario here) and filter down rows. All I need to pass would be the column names by which I want to segment

eg. 
`seg <- c("group", "wk", "source")`

One unique combination to filter rows in df would be
`df %>% filter(group == 1 & wk == 1 & source == "A")`

I wrote a recursive function (get_rows) to do so, but it doesn't seem to do what I want. Could anyone provide inputs on where I'm going wrong ?

```
library(dplyr)

filter_row <- function(df,x)
{
 df %>% filter(group == x$group & wk == x$wk & source == x$source)
}

seg <- c("group", "wk", "source")

get_rows <- function(df,seg,pos = 1, l = list())
{
  while(pos <= (length(seg) + 1))
  {
      if(pos <= length(seg))
        for(j in 1:length(unique(df[,seg[pos]])))
        {
          k <- unique(df[,seg[pos]])
          l[seg[pos]] <- k[j]
          get_rows(df,seg,pos+1,l)
          return()
        }
      if(pos > length(seg))
      {
        tmp <- df %>% filter_row(l)
        <call some function on tmp>
        return()
      }
  }
}

get_rows(df,seg)
```

EDIT: I understand there are prebuilt methods I can use to get what I need, but I'm curious about where I'm going wrong in the recursive function I wrote.

Comment: If you want unique combinations, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363278/how-to-filter-for-unique-combination-of-columns-from-an-r-dataframe).  If you want operators on unique subsections, try [this](http://www.magesblog.com/2012/01/say-it-in-r-with-by-apply-and-friends.html), in particular data.table.

Comment: Thanks ! That's super helpful for this context ! I'm still curious tho about where I'm going wrong in my recursive function

Comment: What makes you think it is recursive? The While loop?

Comment: `split( df, interaction( df[ , c("group", "wk", "source")] ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a data.table/dplyr solution out there, but this one is pretty simple.

```
# Just paste together the values of the column you want to aggregate over.
# This creates a vector of factors
f <- function(data, v) {apply(data[,v,drop=F], 1, paste, collapse = ".")}

# Aggregate, tapply, ave, and a few more functions can do the same thing
by(data = df,                                   # Your data here
   INDICES = f(df, c("group", "wk", "source")), # Your data and columns here
   FUN = identity, simplify = F)                # Your function here
```

Can also use `library(dplyr) and library(data.table)`

```
df %>% data.table %>% group_by(group, wk, source) %>% do(yourfunctionhere, use . for x)
```