# For two sets of co-ordinates, extracting the unique rows of Set A less Set B

Tags: r, excel, unique, combinations, set-operations

I have two sets of co-ordinates:

- Set A one with 49,898 combinations of x and y
- Set B with 36,404 combinations of x and y.
- (Set A has all of the combinations in Set B plus an additional 13,494 combinations)
- solutions in either Excel or R are fine

I want to extract this unique set of 13,494 combinations. For the purpose of trying to extract these unique values using Excel or R, I have copied Set B’s x & y co-ordinate combinations into the same column as Set A’s.

Table layout is two columns `Xcod, Ycod` : [x and y example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYApb.png)

I have read through a number of posts proposing the use of excel & R which partly deal with this problem except the output is always 49,898 combinations because they maintain the ‘original’ set of duplicate values. I understand why this is, but what I would like is to delete those duplicates entirely so that I have a final output containing Set A's unique 13,494 combinations.

[Excel] I used the following: `Data -> Advanced Filter -> Unique records only`

[R] I used the following code from this thread:

```
UniqRemDups <- unique(RemDups[,c('Xcod','Ycod')])
```

[How to filter for unique combination of columns from an R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363278/how-to-filter-for-unique-combination-of-columns-from-an-r-dataframe)

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: In this specific case you seem to have positive integer coordinates in a range, and all multiples of 1000 (in fact 5000). So you could squeeze each coord-pair into one 32b integer representation e.g. `(Xcod/1000)*1e4 + (Ycod/1000)` e.g. `4405*1e4 + 4725 = 44054725`

Comment: You don't want unique combinations between the two sets, you simply want Set A \ Set B, i.e. the set 'less' operation. And those aren't combinations, just plain rows of your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

One way in R using the uniquecombs function from mgcv.

```
data <- structure(list(Xcod = c(4405000L, 4415000L, 4425000L, 4435000L, 
4445000L, 4455000L, 4465000L, 4475000L, 4435000L, 4495000L, 4505000L, 
4515000L, 4525000L, 4535000L, 4545000L, 4555000L, 4565000L, 4575000L, 
4585000L), Ycod = c(4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 
4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 
4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L, 4725000L
)), .Names = c("Xcod", "Ycod"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))

library(mgcv)
unique_rows <- uniquecombs(data)
```

Comment: OP says they have two data sets but your example only has one..?